# Limit Rotation of Object?

Tags: c#, accelerometer, unity-game-engine

In my game, I am rotating a gameobject with the Accelerometer of my phone, here's the code for that:

```
void lookAround1()
{
    float accelx, accely, accelz = 0;
    accelx = Input.acceleration.x;
    accely = Input.acceleration.y;
    accelz = Input.acceleration.z;
    transform.Rotate( accely * Time.deltaTime * 75f, accelx 
    *Time.deltaTime     * 75f, 0);

}
```

**How can I make it so my object can only rotate to about 60 degrees on all three axis'?**

To give a better idea of what I'm talking about, here's a screenshot from the game:[image]

Comment: It is called "[Clamping](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html)" a value. I would post as an answer but "60 degrees of what?" 0,0,0? The initial angle at  scene start? The angle of the previous frame? Also, your picture provides no help in understanding your question. Lastly, [don't put tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103563/can-we-prevent-titles-with-an-unnecessary-tag-in-them). Just tag your question approprately and leave it at that.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain can you make an answer explaining how to do that please? Everything I find online isn't helping. Thanks

Comment: I would if you answered my quetion. 60 degrees from what?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sorry I didn't see the edited part of your question for some reason. 60 degrees from the starting rotation of the GameObject (0,0,0). Thanks for the tips btw.

Comment: Starting rotation at the beginning of the frame or the starting rotation when the object was created?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the rotation for the whole scene you could use the `mathf.clamp` syntax and `clamp` the cameras rotation `.z, .x ans .y` to the values you want